# Crystal Reports mvc

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller, crystal-reports

I made an application with c# mvc 4.8 and I have few reports made with crystal reports.

On Visual Studio 2019 on debug is working perfectly. Once I made a deploy to local IIS the reports not working.

I have the below error. May I have to add something in config file? I have already install runtime sap latest version 64 bit.

**Report Cannot be printed CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The system cannot find the file specified.
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)
at ArsWeb.Controllers.ReportsController.ActivityLogReport(ActivityLog model)**

Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally, there are 2 reasons for this error, you can try the following methods to solve the problem.

**Permission issue**

The application must have access to the Temp folder. You have two choices to solve this (Choose any one).

1.[How to Assign Permissions for the Windows Temporary Folder on the Web Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/commerce-server/aa544650(v=cs.70)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

2.[ASP.NET Impersonation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/xh507fc5(v=vs.71)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

ASPNET machine account to be added to the Temp directory, so we have to specify username and password attributes for  tag in Web.config file for identifying the IIS Authenticated Account or User.

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />
```

**Invalid File path or File name**

1.Ensure the Report file name is correct (may be Typo or something. Example: Repotr1.rpt instead of Report1.rpt).

2.Ensure the Report path is correct (Example: "Reports/Report1.rpt" instead of "~/Reports/Report1.rpt").

3.Actually some of us forget to copy the report files to the publish folder (IIS virtual directory).

Comment: Thanks for reply! I found what was my mistake. I hade installed wrong version of runtime.